# Winbinder not working with PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, winbinder

I've been making a lot of console apps in PHP, but now I'm wanting to try making an actual Windows program.

Since WinBinder is pretty much *the* extension to do this, I went ahead and downloaded it. I put the DLL in the extension folder and added its entry to the php.ini file.

But when I try to run a simple test (`php -r "echo 'Test';"`) I get the following error:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: winbinder: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

I really have no idea what this means, nor what to do about it. Any help resolving this error, or advice for a different extension, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Winbinder for PHP 5.4 here: https://github.com/stefan-loewe/WinBinder

There is no thing prevent you from developing desktop application using PHP.

Comment: Thank you very much for finding this. Now I just need to change from non-thread-safe to thread-safe versions of PHP. I'll let you know how it goes.